# Falha na instalação do pyarrow e fastparquet

Tags: python

Boa tarde, pessoal, sou iniciante em python então por favor, tenham paciência.

Estou tentando ler um arquivo do tipo .parquet, para isso procurei na internet como poderia lê-lo e vi que deveria instalar o pyarrow ou fastparquet.

Sendo assim tentei o **pip install pyarrow** no meu jupyter botebook e ele não pára de rodar (fica aquele asterisco do lado da célula). Tentei então pelo prompt de comando, e recebo um erro:

**Error: Failed building wheel for pyarrow** (em vermelho)

**Failed to build pyarrow** (em branco)

**Error: Could not build wheels for pyarrow which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly** (em vermelho)

Claro que tem mais texto em vermelho, mas não sei se vale a pena copiar tudo então deixei as últimas 3 mensagens que aparecem. Talvez isso já ajude vocês a me ajudar.

Tentei o mesmo procedimento para o **fastparquet**, no jupyter botebook a mesma situação (não pára de rodar) e no prompt de comando uma resposta diferente, mas muito texto em vermelho e, no final das contas, nada feito. Aqui o erro parece ser que preciso do Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 (**Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required.**).

Alguém poderia me ajudar a entender porque não consigo baixar o pyarrow? Ou se existe uma forma mais simples de ler e manipular um arquivo do tipo parquet que eu não tenha pensado, agradeço.

Minha versão do Python é a 3.7.4.

Atenciosamente.
Bia.

Comment: Tenta `pip install apache-superset`

Comment: @Paulo Marques, você sugere instalar o Apache Superset para poder manipular dados em parquet? Ou porque nele contém o pyarrow? Vi na internet que ele é uma ferramenta de Business Intelligence, ou ele também é um "módulo/biblioteca" ou eu que não entendi nada? Quero e preciso usar o jupyter notebook então não quero nem posso usar outra platafornma para resolver este problema.

Comment: Acabei de perceber que existe uma mensagem de que ele não é suportado em Windows 32-bit, mas o meu sistema é 64-bit. Não estou entendendo mais nada. Quando digito python no meu prompt de comando recebo **Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:16:31) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32**

Comment: A sugestão era porque ele continha o pyarrow...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olá,

Veja se funciona dessa forma:

```
python -m pip install --no-use-pep517 pyarrow
```

Answer (score 0):

Faça o seguinte, amigo: abra o Prompt de Comando; em seguida, digite pip install pyarrow e dê ente.

file_parquet=r'C:\Users\AfonsoSoaresLeiteNet\Documents\arquivoparquet\dados.teste.parquet' -- caminho do arquivo

pd.read_parquet(file_parquet, engine='auto' ) -- saída/visualização do arquivo

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).